# Failing getting checkboxes values on the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a web page with a lot of checkboxes in the view in this form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PerformDiagnostic", "Tests", FormMethod.Post))
{
   (...)
   @Html.CheckBox("Something01", false)<span>Something 01</span><br />
   @Html.CheckBox("Something02", false)<span>Something 02</span><br />
   (...)
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

When I press submit button, I pass all the checkboxes statuses to the controller that has the following signature:

```
    public ActionResult DoSomeTasks(FormCollection form)
    {
        int isSomething01Checked= Convert.ToInt32(form["Something01"]);
        int isSomething02Checked= Convert.ToInt32(form["Something02"]);

        ....
    }
```

In the controller I want to know for each checkbox whether it is checked or unchecked but the problem is that form["SomethingXX"] returns something like {true,false} but it is not telling me its current status (checked or unchecked). Also what return form["SomethingXX"] cannot be converted.

I have checked that if checkbox is checked, form["SomethingXX"] returns {true,false} and if it is unchecked then form["SomethingXX"] returns {false}, I do not understand why when checkbox is checked is returning  {true,false} instead of {true}.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems like you're needlessly do an end-run around the MVC pattern, and therefore missing out on the convenience of pre-defined model binding.  Why not just create a strongly-typed model?

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Display(Name="Something 01")]
    public bool Something01 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Something 02")]
    public bool Something02 { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the HTML helper to generate check-boxes for the model properties:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Something01)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Something02)
```

And now the controller code is straight-forward.  Simply call for the view-model type:

```
public ActionResult DoSomeTasks(ViewModel model)
{
    bool isSomething01Checked = model.Something01;
    bool isSomething02Checked = model.Something02;
}
```